# bb 10 cascades sqlite relationship table

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I need to create two tables like,

Table Name-1

```
 ID                              : primary Kay(Integer)                          

 Name                         : String

 Status                        : Boolean 

 DateTime                    : Data Time
```

Table Name-2

```
 ID                             : feign-key (ID of Table Name-1 which is primary key)     

 Symbol_ID                : String
```

There should be  feign-key Relationship between Table-1 and Table-2

how  to create tables , insert data , delete and read data from them !!!

Comment: How about [Working with SQL](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/data_access/working_with_sql.html)

Comment: sqlite has nothing to do with blackbery or android ios,you may search your queries using `'sqlite'` tag.

Comment: if you know table normalization means then just use search query only.